# Low memory bandwidth

Tags: memory, hardware, bandwidth

I have *ddr2-667* ram and I measured my memory bandwidth via STREAM tool.

Here is my results:

```
Function     Rate (MB/s)   Avg time     Min time     Max time
Copy:        2229.0490       0.0158       0.0144     0.0206
Scale:       2208.1095       0.0160       0.0145     0.0216
Add:         2620.2118       0.0196       0.0183     0.0208
Triad:       2358.1446       0.0217       0.0204     0.0246
```

But theoretically my memory bandwidth is 5333 Mb/s.

Why my bandwidth results is very low ? is there a solution to increase (e.g overclock)

Comment: This is not a StackOverflow question. Try on [superUser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: You can try stream2 http://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/stream2/ I've used both before and I think you can't reach the theoretical value. Sadly I don't remember the explanations for that.

Answer (score 0):

First, as SamGamgee said, reaching theoretical memory bandwidth is hard.

Using multiple threads *could* increase the measured bandwidth, though. STREAM by default disables multi-thread support, though. You can enable it by adding -fopenmp (if you are using GCC) to the compile option to enable multi-thread support.